# How to browse securely, anonymously and without blocks on Android?

Tags: security, privacy, vpn, proxy, https

So here's your Average Joe at a coffee store, using the open Wifi on his shiny new Android phone. Obviously there are the same issues with using a laptop or any other device on an open network, including having the Hotspot owner as well as other users snooping on poor Joe's web traffic. What sorts of solutions exist for dear Joe?

Joe finishes his coffee and heads to work, and his work Wifi is set up with a proxy (with username and password authentication) to 'protect' (as well as monitor) their workers from such useful sites as Superuser when Joe would really like to utilize such sites. Of course, Joe is obedient and uses Proxydroid which does allow his browser access to his works' white listed sites, though he can only access sites using http connections, a further let down as Joe really does like to check his email and do some banking on his phone. Joe has tried solutions like Orbot, by Tor, though that doesn't seem to work. **How can Joe get past these issues?**

Obviously this is phrased in a rather happy-go-lucky manner, though certainly the first point is a serious issue for many Android users.
All comments are taken gratefully.

Comment: Has Joe tried using the Opera Browser, as everything you do with Opera is pushed through the Opera proxy server?  They call it a feature, since they will compress images and such to speed up performance on mobile phones... but it also has the advantage of... well... being pushed through a proxy.

Comment: @BonGart Is the connection to Opera's servers secure?

Comment: @BonGart I have tried Opera and it doesn't appear to work with work's set up, unless I set it up to use their proxy.

Matthew Read Apparently the servers use encrypted connections.

Answer (score 3):

If Joe's device is rooted and Joe has a server (with full SSH access) running somewhere on internet, Joe should use SSH Tunnel app with socks proxy option checked (for dynamic port forwarding). There's no need to install VPN server or proxy server. There's no need to do complicated configurations on server. Plus, Joe's data will be secured inside powerful encrypted tunnel, too. With this method, Joe's data will be under his own control (There's no involvement of third-party services).

Comment: I'm hoping to answer this both for myself as well as others out there running Android, and despite personally having a rooted phone, many do not.

Sadly I sit behind a firewall and router that doesn't allow port forwarding, though I intend to get a server set up with a third party.

Thanks for the response.

Comment: @Kryptonite The firewall and router can't detect anything inside SSH Tunnel because traffic is encrypted. So, they can't block such port forwarding. In fact, all of traffic will use port of SSH (default 22).

Answer (score 1):

well, Joe is a smart guy who has already reached the solution by researching VPN technology, it solves the issues of security from non social elements (hackers and sneakers) in an open wifi hotspot, the VPNs like [hidemyass](http://www.bestvpnservice.com/providers/21/hide_my_ass!.html) or [Purevpn](http://bestvpnservice.com/providers/30/purevpn.html) will help better in this regard, thanks